# Problem with identifying a component

Tags: identification, motherboard

What is this little part called?

[image: busted part]

It seems to be burnt, does this require the replacement of the whole motherboard?

Comment: we can't tell, everything on top of that package is burnt, and we're not clairvoyant. However, let's be honest, this is a repair question in disguise without engineering background, and these are off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: Look at the fat trace it's connected to - follow that trace down & to the right (as your pic is oriented), you'll see another 8-pin device connected to that trace. The smoked part is *probably the same as this other one. Your pic is too fuzzy for me to make out the details. But there's no was to know with just a pic if there's some underlying fault which caused the first part to die.

Comment: I didn't know this is off topic here, and yes it is a repair question, i am not really knowledgeable in any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a MOSFET, as part of a switching power supply- either the switch or a synchronous rectifier MOSFET.

As to whether it would work if the MOSFET (and possibly the one next it) were replaced, hard to say. Other things may have been destroyed.